How to load an LDR file using THREE.js
I am attempting to display an .ldr file in a web page using THREE.js. An .ldr file is a LEGO version of a .mpd file. The THREE.js documentation says to convert the .ldr file to a packed .mpd file, which I have done successfully.
Note: .ldr is a LEGO LDraw file, and a .mpd is a 3D Models to Print file.
I then used the .ldr example from the LDrawLoader documentation and this works. However, I want the simplest version of displaying the .mpd file. The example code has a preloader, a small GUI, and the option to select from a list of .mpd files.
I have attempted to remove the GUI and preloader but it stops everything from working. I've tried the code from the documentation (not the examples page) and a similar set of code from the LDraw forum.
I have had limited experience with THREE.js and anything related to 3D animation.
Here is my current working code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js webgl - LDrawLoader</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <style>
            body {
                color: #444;
            }
            a {
                color: #08f;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <script type="importmap">
            {
                "imports": {
                    "three": "../build/three.module.js",
                    "three/addons/": "./jsm/"
                }
            }
        </script>

        <script type="module">

            import * as THREE from 'three';

            import { GUI } from 'three/addons/libs/lil-gui.module.min.js';

            import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';
            import { RoomEnvironment } from 'three/addons/environments/RoomEnvironment.js';

            import { LDrawLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/LDrawLoader.js';
            import { LDrawUtils } from 'three/addons/utils/LDrawUtils.js';
            import { LDrawConditionalLineMaterial } from 'three/addons/materials/LDrawConditionalLineMaterial.js';

            let container, progressBarDiv;

            let camera, scene, renderer, controls, gui, guiData;

            let model;

            const ldrawPath = 'models/';

            const modelFileList = {
                'Car': 'car.ldr_Packed.mpd',
                'Block': 'block.ldr_Packed.mpd',
            };

            init();

            function init() {

                container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( container );

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
                camera.position.set( 150, 200, 250 );

                //

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                renderer.setAnimationLoop( animate );
                renderer.toneMapping = THREE.ACESFilmicToneMapping;
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                // scene

                const pmremGenerator = new THREE.PMREMGenerator( renderer );

                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xdeebed );
                scene.environment = pmremGenerator.fromScene( new RoomEnvironment() ).texture;

                controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
                controls.enableDamping = true;

                //

                guiData = {
                    modelFileName: modelFileList[ 'Car' ],
                    displayLines: true,
                    conditionalLines: true,
                    smoothNormals: true,
                    buildingStep: 0,
                    noBuildingSteps: 'No steps.',
                    flatColors: false,
                    mergeModel: false
                };

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize );

                progressBarDiv = document.createElement( 'div' );
                progressBarDiv.innerText = 'Loading...';
                progressBarDiv.style.fontSize = '3em';
                progressBarDiv.style.color = '#888';
                progressBarDiv.style.display = 'block';
                progressBarDiv.style.position = 'absolute';
                progressBarDiv.style.top = '50%';
                progressBarDiv.style.width = '100%';
                progressBarDiv.style.textAlign = 'center';


                // load materials and then the model

                reloadObject( true );

            }

            function updateObjectsVisibility() {

                model.traverse( c => {

                    if ( c.isLineSegments ) {

                        if ( c.isConditionalLine ) {

                            c.visible = guiData.conditionalLines;

                        } else {

                            c.visible = guiData.displayLines;

                        }

                    } else if ( c.isGroup ) {

                        // Hide objects with building step > gui setting
                        c.visible = c.userData.buildingStep <= guiData.buildingStep;

                    }

                } );

            }

            function reloadObject( resetCamera ) {

                if ( model ) {

                    scene.remove( model );

                }

                model = null;

                updateProgressBar( 0 );
                showProgressBar();

                // only smooth when not rendering with flat colors to improve processing time
                const lDrawLoader = new LDrawLoader();

        const loader = new LDrawLoader();

                lDrawLoader.setConditionalLineMaterial( LDrawConditionalLineMaterial );
                lDrawLoader.smoothNormals = guiData.smoothNormals && ! guiData.flatColors;
                lDrawLoader
                    .setPath( ldrawPath )
                    .load( guiData.modelFileName, function ( group2 ) {

                        if ( model ) {

                            scene.remove( model );

                        }

                        model = group2;

                        // demonstrate how to use convert to flat colors to better mimic the lego instructions look
                        if ( guiData.flatColors ) {

                            function convertMaterial( material ) {

                                const newMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
                                newMaterial.color.copy( material.color );
                                newMaterial.polygonOffset = material.polygonOffset;
                                newMaterial.polygonOffsetUnits = material.polygonOffsetUnits;
                                newMaterial.polygonOffsetFactor = material.polygonOffsetFactor;
                                newMaterial.opacity = material.opacity;
                                newMaterial.transparent = material.transparent;
                                newMaterial.depthWrite = material.depthWrite;
                                newMaterial.toneMapping = false;

                                return newMaterial;

                            }

                            model.traverse( c => {

                                if ( c.isMesh ) {

                                    if ( Array.isArray( c.material ) ) {

                                        c.material = c.material.map( convertMaterial );

                                    } else {

                                        c.material = convertMaterial( c.material );

                                    }

                                }

                            } );

                        }

                        // Merge model geometries by material
                        if ( guiData.mergeModel ) model = LDrawUtils.mergeObject( model );

                        // Convert from LDraw coordinates: rotate 180 degrees around OX
                        model.rotation.x = Math.PI;

                        scene.add( model );

                        guiData.buildingStep = model.userData.numBuildingSteps - 1;

                        updateObjectsVisibility();

                        // Adjust camera and light

                        const bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( model );
                        const size = bbox.getSize( new THREE.Vector3() );
                        const radius = Math.max( size.x, Math.max( size.y, size.z ) ) * 0.5;

                        if ( resetCamera ) {

                            controls.target0.copy( bbox.getCenter( new THREE.Vector3() ) );
                            controls.position0.set( - 2.3, 1, 2 ).multiplyScalar( radius ).add( controls.target0 );
                            controls.reset();

                        }

                        createGUI();

                        hideProgressBar();

                    }, onProgress, onError );

            }

            function onWindowResize() {

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            }

            function createGUI() {

                if ( gui ) {

                    gui.destroy();

                }

                gui = new GUI();

                gui.add( guiData, 'modelFileName', modelFileList ).name( 'Model' ).onFinishChange( function () {

                    reloadObject( true );

                } );

                gui.add( guiData, 'flatColors' ).name( 'Flat Colors' ).onChange( function () {

                    reloadObject( false );

                } );

                gui.add( guiData, 'mergeModel' ).name( 'Merge model' ).onChange( function () {

                    reloadObject( false );

                } );

                if ( model.userData.numBuildingSteps > 1 ) {

                    gui.add( guiData, 'buildingStep', 0, model.userData.numBuildingSteps - 1 ).step( 1 ).name( 'Building step' ).onChange( updateObjectsVisibility );

                } else {

                    gui.add( guiData, 'noBuildingSteps' ).name( 'Building step' ).onChange( updateObjectsVisibility );

                }

                gui.add( guiData, 'smoothNormals' ).name( 'Smooth Normals' ).onChange( function changeNormals() {

                    reloadObject( false );

                } );

                gui.add( guiData, 'displayLines' ).name( 'Display Lines' ).onChange( updateObjectsVisibility );
                gui.add( guiData, 'conditionalLines' ).name( 'Conditional Lines' ).onChange( updateObjectsVisibility );

            }

            //

            function animate() {

                controls.update();
                render();

            }

            function render() {

                renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }

            function onProgress( xhr ) {

                if ( xhr.lengthComputable ) {

                    updateProgressBar( xhr.loaded / xhr.total );

                    console.log( Math.round( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100, 2 ) + '% downloaded' );

                }

            }

            function onError( error ) {

                const message = 'Error loading model';
                progressBarDiv.innerText = message;
                console.log( message );
                console.error( error );

            }

            function showProgressBar() {

                document.body.appendChild( progressBarDiv );

            }

            function hideProgressBar() {

                document.body.removeChild( progressBarDiv );

            }

            function updateProgressBar( fraction ) {

                progressBarDiv.innerText = 'Loading... ' + Math.round( fraction * 100, 2 ) + '%';

            }

        </script>       

    </body>
</html>

I have a GitHub repo with different attempts here:
https://github.com/codeadamca/nodejs-three-ldr
The best code is one called working.html.
To summarize, I want to remove the GUI and preloader from the THREE.js LDrawLoader example.
